# How do I provide multiple menu tabs for a view?

Tags: views, routes

I have a view to select many articles with a specific taxonomy term with a path of
     Example.com/materials/%
where the % uses a contextual filter to pick the correct material. The filter works.

Each article can be further subcategorized to discuss various subjects regarding the material and is given a path such as
     Example.com/materials/%/general or Example.com/materials/%/standards

I thought I would be able to display a default view for  materials/%   and have menu tabs defined by variations of the view to display /general or /scope parts.

I cannot get any menu tabs to display with the view.

Please respond with any questions, suggestions or alternative approaches that have worked for you.

Thanks

Comment: Possibly relate to this question
http://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/16110/problem-trying-to-create-a-views-with-tabs-link-of-tab-doesnt-point-to-the-pat

Worths a check.

Answer (score 2):

I have solved this problem using the [Quicktabs](http://drupal.org/project/quicktabs) module.

I use a panel to set a page where I can put a quicktabs block, then I call different views with each tabs, also you can even set arguments.