# Problem trying to create a views with tabs. Link of tab doesn't point to the path I set

Tags: views, routes

I am trying to create a views with tabs: 
so that a page that has several tabs, the View has a primary page that shows all Article nodes, a tab for all Event nodes, and a tab for Blog nodes.
Something should works like this:

[image]

- "Content" button in menu links to /content,
- "Articles" tab links to /content/articles,
- "Blog" tab links to /content/blog,
- "Event" tab links to /content/event.

---

However, with my work, this is what I got:

[image]

**all the 3 tabs link to /content**, instead of /content/articles, /content/blog, /content/event.

==========

Below is configuration of my view:

1. [image]
2. [image]
3. [image]
4. [image]
5. [image]
6. [image]
7. [image]
8. [image]
9. [image]

So basically, the tabs shows up, but the links of tabs are all pointed to /content, rather than their individual link.

What have I done wrong? Please advise. Thanks in advanced!

Comment: ++ question.  Related questions are often posted, but the graphic depiction makes the question easy to understand.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I've not had the pleasure of Views 3, but I think I can see what's wrong. I believe you want to have three displays:

1. Articles, which has a default menu tab (and you want Views to provide the parent menu item)
2. Blog, which has a menu tab (but not default)
3. Events, which has a menu tab (but not default)

(Currently the displays are set up as default tabs, which is why they point to the parent item - just like the path for the *View* tab on a node view doesn't point to `node/x/view` but points simply to `node/x`.)

Answer (score 0):

I think I see your mistake.  Similar to the above post, you need more views.  Just one though.  Right after the instructions for creating the Content view, the book has a line  " + Add new view".  In my book (hard copy version) it's at the very top of page 79.  I think you missed that step. You might clone the view you have and delete the appropriate displays to save time, or just create a new one from scratch.

Also you might try the book's site. www.dgd7.org

Sometimes the authors themselves respond to questions there.